# Junit throwing initialization error. Method 'com' not found

Tags: java, junit

[image]

All the tests are passing . What should I add for this error to disappear? I am assuming  some annotation need to be added. It says Method 'com' not found. I am not able to debug . I dont know what is it talking about.

Code:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

import java.util.List;


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

public class test {


    @Autowired
    private  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcImpl jdbcImpl;

    @Autowired
    private MConfiguration config;

    @Autowired
    private MUtilities util;


    @Test
    public void testRetervices() throws Exception {
        List<Tervice> marketServices = jdbcImpl.retrieveTervices("em", "Coitis");
        assertEquals(marketServices.size(), 4);
    }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a step-by-step description of what you do in your eclipse to get this error message.

Comment: Hi Progman, I just right clicked src/test/java folder and selected "run as -> junit test". If I don mvn package in git-bash , I get the same error there as well [INFO] Running com.citi.mdh.totem.live.dao.MarketDataTotemDaoJdbcImplTest
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.citi.mdh.totem.live.dao.MarketDataTotemDaoJdbcImplTest
[ERROR] initializationError  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.Exception: No runnable methods

Comment: Also to add to @Progman, use code snippets, instead of pictures... as to helping you it's hard to tell, but it might be issue with packages.

Comment: @ŠimonKocúrek Updated the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This got fixed when I changed the package from 
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test; to 
import org.junit.Test;

Thanks!